# Callbacks and custom socket client in Android

Tags: android, sockets

I used code from this tutorial https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/04/27/node-js-android-tcpip/, but got the such errors:

> Cannot resolve method 'send(java.lang.String)'
>
> Cannot resolve method 'disconnect()'

Problem in Client.java class, which I created from tutorial (link above), but I can't resolve this problem.

> **MainActivity.java**

```
void doIt() {
    Client socket = new Client("192.168.0.8", 1234);
    socket.setClientCallback(new Client.ClientCallback () {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(String message) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnect(Socket socket) {
            socket.send("Hello World!\n");
            socket.disconnect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnect(Socket socket, String message) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectError(Socket socket, String message) {
        }
    });

    socket.connect();
}
```

> **Client.java**

```
public class Client {
private Socket socket;
private OutputStream socketOutput;
private BufferedReader socketInput;

private String ip;
private int port;
private ClientCallback listener=null;

public Client(String ip, int port){
    this.ip=ip;
    this.port=port;
}

public void connect(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            socket = new Socket();
            InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port);
            try {
                socket.connect(socketAddress);
                socketOutput = socket.getOutputStream();
                socketInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                new ReceiveThread().start();

                if(listener!=null)
                    listener.onConnect(socket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if(listener!=null)
                    listener.onConnectError(socket, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void disconnect(){
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if(listener!=null)
            listener.onDisconnect(socket, e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void send(String message){
    try {
        socketOutput.write(message.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if(listener!=null)
            listener.onDisconnect(socket, e.getMessage());
    }
}

private class ReceiveThread extends Thread implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        String message;
        try {
            while((message = socketInput.readLine()) != null) {   // each line must end with a \n to be received
                if(listener!=null)
                    listener.onMessage(message);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(listener!=null)
                listener.onDisconnect(socket, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public void setClientCallback(ClientCallback listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}

public void removeClientCallback(){
    this.listener=null;
}

public interface ClientCallback {
    void onMessage(String message);
    void onConnect(Socket socket);
    void onDisconnect(Socket socket, String message);
    void onConnectError(Socket socket, String message);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're calling those methods on `Socket` (which comes from your callback) and not on your `Client` (which is in another scope) because they have the same name and java will use the smallest variable scope.

Change the name of your callback variable or the name of your Client variable and it should work when using the correct one :)

Ex:

```
void doIt() {
    final Client myClient = new Client("192.168.0.8", 1234);
    myClient.setClientCallback(new Client.ClientCallback () {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(String message) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnect(Socket socket) {
            myClient.send("Hello World!\n");
            myClient.disconnect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnect(Socket socket, String message) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectError(Socket socket, String message) {
        }
    });

    myClient.connect();
}
```